# Mock two separate responses to same function in same test

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking

In my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35732487/1344579) question, I asked how to Mock a class that wraps `requests.get` in my class. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35733015/1344579) provided works well, if I am only calling `requests.get` once. However, it turns out my class is more complicated than I made my example.

My class calls `request.get` twice. Once at initialization, because it hits an API end point that returns API values I need to use in my actual request, and once when I make my `.fetch` call.

```
import requests
class ExampleAPI(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.important_tokens = requests.get(url_to_tokens)['tokens']

    def fetch(self, url, params=None, key=None, token=None, **kwargs):
        return requests.get(url, params=self.important_tokens).json()
```

Now, it turns out I need to create two mock responses. One for the initialization and one for the `.fetch`. Using the code from the previous answer:

```
@patch('mymodule.requests.get')
def test_fetch(self, fake_get):
    expected = {"result": "True"}
    fake_get.return_value.json.return_value = expected
    e = ExampleAPI()    # This needs one set of mocked responses
    self.assertEqual(e.fetch('http://my.api.url.example.com'), expected)    # This needs a second set
```

How can I create seperate responses for these two seperate calls to `request.get`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can assign an iterable to the `side_effects` attribute of a mock object; each time the mock is called, it returns the next item of the iterable.

```
fake_responses = [Mock(), Mock()]
fake_responses[0].json.return_value = ...
fake_responses[1].json.return_value = ...
fake_get.side_effects = fake_responses
```

Comment: This seems to be passing `<MagicMock name='fetch()' id='46383904'>` instead of the return value, even though the `fake_responses[0].json.return_value` has the correct values.

Comment: @NewGuy I have the same problem, how did you solve the MagicMock in your response?

Comment: I have the same problem as above. Did somebody manage to solve this?

Comment: It helped me. Key thing here: [Using `side_effect` to return a sequence of values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect)

Comment: @Denis how did you resolve it? Just using a list does not work.

Comment: @Rick I needed to call same function a few times with different results. So I used a function (particular raised an exception) as side effect 1st time and `None` 2nd time, as linked docks describe: "If you pass in a function it will be called with same arguments as the mock and unless the function returns the DEFAULT singleton the call to the mock will then return whatever the function returns..."

Answer (score 7):

Looks like the previous answer was using "side_effects" instead of "side_effect". This is how you can do that in Python 3:

```
import requests
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from unittest.mock import Mock


class Tests(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('requests.get')
    def test_post_price_band(self, fake_get):
        fake_responses = [Mock(), Mock()]
        fake_responses[0].json.return_value = {"a": 1}
        fake_responses[1].json.return_value = {"b": 2}
        fake_get.side_effect = fake_responses

        r1 = requests.get('https://www.api.com').json()
        self.assertEqual(r1, {"a": 1})

        r2 = requests.get('https://www.api.com').json()
        self.assertEqual(r2, {"b": 2})
```

Alternatively you could implement it like so:

```
class MockResponse:
    def __init__(self, json_data, status_code=requests.codes.ok):
        self.json_data = json_data
        self.status_code = status_code

    def json(self):
        return self.json_data


class Tests(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('requests.get')
    def test_post_price_band(self, fake_get):
        fake_get.side_effect = [
            MockResponse({"a": 1}),
            MockResponse({"b": 2})
        ]

        r1 = requests.get('https://www.api.com')
        self.assertEqual(r1.status_code, requests.codes.ok)
        self.assertEqual(r1.json(), {"a": 1})

        r2 = requests.get('https://www.api.com')
        self.assertEqual(r2.status_code, requests.codes.ok)
        self.assertEqual(r2.json(), {"b": 2})
```

Also check out this library to help you: https://github.com/getsentry/responses

Answer (score 0):

I suppose an improvement to the given answers could be passing an object to the `side_effect` parameter. In case of an iterable, let's suppose we are mocking `requests.get` which is called `n` number of times, to mock every `request.get` call we pass an iterable of length `n`.

A possible improvement over an iterable could be an object which returns a mock function based on one of the parameters the mock function is supposed to use. In case of `requests.get` it can be the `url`. The following class demonstrates this use.

```
class UrlSideEffect:
    def __init__(self, url_fn_map: dict):
        """this class returns a function according to url being passed in the mock call"""
        self.url_fn_map = url_fn_map
    
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        current_url = kwargs["url"]
        f = self.url_fn_map.get(current_url)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
```

A Mock response class which behaves as the mocked object the mocked function will return:

```
from requests import Response
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict

class MockResponse(Response):
    def __init__(self, status_code: int, headers: Dict, text: str) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.status_code = status_code
        self.headers = headers
        self._text = text

    text = property(lambda obj: obj._text)
```

Putting together everything ...

```
mocked_response_url1 = MockResponse(200, {headers:1}, "{json_response:ok, url:url1}")
mocked_response_url2 = MockResponse(200, {headers:1}, "{json_response:ok, url:url2}")

side_effect_mocked_response = UrlSideEffect(
    url_fn_map={"https://url1/": lambda *args, **kwargs: mocked_response_url1,
                "https://url2/":lambda *args, **kwargs: mocked_response_url2
               }
          )

import unittest
class TestExampleAPI(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch("requests.get", side_effect=side_effect_mocked_response)
    def test_initialization_and_fetch(self, _: Any) -> None:
        api = ExampleAPI() # requests.get will return mocked_response_url1
        resp = api.fetch(url2) #requests.get will return mocked_response_url2
        
        # here goes whatever you want to assert ...
```

This approach can also be used in case of asynchronous requests. Imagine having a list of tasks being executed by `asyncio.gather`. Due to the order of requests not being synchronous we cannot pass an iterable to the `side_effect` parameter. Hence in such case the class `UrlSideEffect` can be useful as it is tied to url and not the order of function calls.

Please also have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64992044/pytest-mock-multiple-calls-of-same-method-with-different-side-effect) which inspired my answer.